# Toggle Function Appends Divs instead of Toggling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle two divs onclick. Since I can't share all my code, let me explain what I have.

I have two functions `formatGraph` and `formatTable` that displays json data as a table and graph.

I have the two functions appended to two different divs, a main div that wraps up the two, and an empty div that serves as my container, wrapping up everything.

I have an if statement that checks for when to show or hide the divs. I am calling the formatData function somewhere in my fetch call while rendering my result(I have included the code). I have a css file with the following code:

```
.displayTable {
    display: none;
}

.displayGraph{
    display: block;
}
```

When I load the page, it displays as graph, but when i click the button, it displays the table data (appending it to the existing chart data)
What am I getting wrong?

```
const formatData = (response) => {
const containerDiv = document.createElement("div");

    const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const div1= document.createElement("div");
    div1.classList.add("displayTable");
    div1.appendChild(formatTable(response));
    mainDiv.appendChild(div1)

    const div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.classList.add("displayGraph");
    div2.appendChild(formatGraph(response));
    mainDiv.appendChild(div2)
    containerDiv.append(mainDiv);

    
  const displayButton= document.getElementById("display");
 display.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const displayTable = document.querySelector(".displayTable");
    const displayGraph = document.querySelector(".displayGraph");

 
      if (displayTable.style.display === "none") {
        displayTable.style.display = "none";
        displayGraph.style.display = "block";
    
        
      } else {
         
        displayGraph.style.display === "none";
        displayTable.style.display = "block";
        
      }
    }
  });
  
  return containerDiv;
};
```

The above function is called in my fetch call, and is being appended to my result div, which is the div that displays all the other results in my code. In my fetch call, if a url has 'report,' the above format function is called, else a different function(which I haven't shared is called). I am guessing that the result div doesn't clear before appending the containerDiv.

How can I handle its life cycle?

```
function dataFetch(http://data-entries:8002/v1/data/) {
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.innerHTML = "";

  const request = {
    method: "GET",
  };

  fetch(http://data-entries:8002/v1/data/, request)
   .then(response => response.json())
 .then((items) => {
      result.innerHTML = "";
      if (Array.isArray(items)) {
        if (url.indexOf("report") >= 0) {
          result.append(formatData(items));
        } else {
          data.forEach((item) => {
            result.append(formatReport(item));
          });
        }
      } 
    })

     .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`displayGraph.style.display === "none";`

to

`displayGraph.style.display = "none";`

in the else block.

Comment: This works. However, when the page displays the table and i click my button to toggle it back to the graph, nothing changes. Any suggestion on why?

Comment: I notice your indentation is sloppy. I know it seems non essential but seriously, always make sure the indentation is right. It will help you avoid so many bugs. Use https://beautifier.io/ to auto format your code. Unless I miss my guess this issue is somehow due to the extra `}` on the line just above `return containerDiv;`. I don't know why that would cause this particular issue but I'm pretty sure it's confusing things since it means `return containerDiv;` is outside of the `formatData` function.